# How can I change the order of accounts in the iOS Calendar app?

Tags: ios, calendar, ical, accounts

I have an iCloud and Gmail account set up in the Calendar app on iOS. The Gmail account is shown at the top, but I would prefer to have it below the iCloud account.

Is there any way to change the order of accounts in the Calendar?

I can’t find an option in the UI. If there is some workaround (like removing/adding the accounts in a certain order), I would be happy with that as well.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There’s no way in the iOS version of Calendars to reorder your specific accounts and even if you’re able to accomplish this on your Mac, it won’t carry over.

I’ve also tried renaming the accounts to force an order alphabetically but that also does not affect the order.

If this is a must-have feature, you will likely need to look at a 3rd party Calendar app for iOS unfortunately.

Comment: Wow. 2023 and that's still the case. How weird, annoying and honestly kinda sad...